# aio_write on Large Files

Tags: c, aio

I'm trying to essentially mimic the functionality of [`sendfile(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html) in an asynchronous fashion using [`aio_read(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/aio_read.3.html) and [`aio_write(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/aio_write.3.html).

Everything seems to be working fine, with the exception of testing large (> 150k) files.

I have a simple `struct io_request` I am using to keep track of the transfers:

```
struct io_request {
    int status;
    struct aiocb *aiocbp;
    int sfd;
};
```

First, I build the `aio_read()` call:

```
struct io_request * ioreq = malloc(sizeof(struct io_request));
ioreq->status = EINPROGRESS;
ioreq->sfd = sfd;

struct aiocb * aiocbreq = malloc(sizeof(struct aiocb));
memset(aiocbreq, 0, sizeof(struct aiocb));

ioreq->aiocbp = aiocbreq;

ioreq->aiocbp->aio_fildes = ffd;

if (ioreq->aiocbp->aio_fildes == -1) {
    perror("aio_fildes");
}

ioreq->aiocbp->aio_buf = malloc(st.st_size);
if (ioreq->aiocbp->aio_buf == NULL) {
    perror("aio_buf malloc");
}

ioreq->aiocbp->aio_nbytes = st.st_size;
ioreq->aiocbp->aio_reqprio = 0;
ioreq->aiocbp->aio_offset = 0;
ioreq->aiocbp->aio_sigevent.sigev_signo = IO_READ_SIGNAL;
ioreq->aiocbp->aio_sigevent.sigev_value.sival_ptr = ioreq;
if (aio_read(ioreq->aiocbp) == -1) {
    perror("aio_read");
}
```

Which then later is captured in a `IO_READ_SIGNAL` handler:

```
static void
aio_read_handler(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *ucontext)
{
    if (si->si_code == SI_ASYNCIO) {
        struct io_request *ioreq = si->si_value.sival_ptr;

        // Build the AIO write request
        struct aiocb aiocbreq;
        memset(&aiocbreq, 0, sizeof(struct aiocb));
        aiocbreq.aio_fildes = ioreq->sfd;
        aiocbreq.aio_buf = ioreq->aiocbp->aio_buf;
        aiocbreq.aio_nbytes = ioreq->aiocbp->aio_nbytes;
        aiocbreq.aio_sigevent.sigev_signo = IO_WRITE_SIGNAL;
        aiocbreq.aio_sigevent.sigev_value.sival_ptr = ioreq;

        if (aio_write((void *) &aiocbreq) == -1) {
            perror("aio_write");
        }
    }
}
```

I can confirm that inside the handler, even for large files, the contents of `ioreq->aiocbp->aio_buf` is full and complete.

Later, the `aio_write()` is captured in a `IO_WRITE_SIGNAL` handler:

```
static void
aio_write_handler(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *ucontext)
{
    if (si->si_code == SI_ASYNCIO) {
        struct io_request *ioreq = si->si_value.sival_ptr;

        ssize_t bytes_written = aio_return(ioreq->aiocbp);
        printf("Wrote %zu of %zu bytes\n", bytes_written, ioreq->aiocbp->aio_nbytes);
        //free(ioreq->aiocbp);
        //free(ioreq);

        if (aio_error(ioreq->aiocbp) != 0) {
            perror("aio_write_handler");
        }
    }
}
```

At this point `aio_write()` should have been completed. I check the return values and act accordingly. Both calls report the appropriate number of bytes have been written and no errors arose during the write.

The greater application is an HTTP server. I speculate that this problem arrises because the remote client cannot read fast enough to keep up with the `aio_write()`. When I had a `sendfile()` implementation of this, I had to call `sendfile()` multiple times to complete the file transfer.

Several direct questions:

- Why does `aio_return()` and `aio_error()` not report any problems?
- How can I fix this behavior?
- Are there ways to buffer `aio_write()`? I was thinking of capping of `n_bytes` inside `struct aiocb` passed to `aio_write()`, and just calling `aio_write()` multiple times from inside `aio_write_handler()`.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: James, I've read this several times, and I'm still not sure what the problem is that you're experiencing.  Maybe it got lost in an edit?  Perhaps, it'd help to include some of the output from `aio_write_handler`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're using `aio_return` before `aio_error`.  The `aio_return` man page says,

> This  function  should be called only once for any given request, after
>          **aio_error**(3) returns something other than **EINPROGRESS**.